# Are there any perils with quit and exit in matlab?

Tags: matlab, exit, quit

I have not thought so much of this before I started learning c++ and I have not needed to terminate matlab from a program so many times before. The question just occured to me:

Are there any perils in using the functions `quit` and `exit` in matlab? I know that these functions should never be used except for emergencies in c++. However, in my little dream world matlabs functions are in most cases stable which speaks towards that matlab do a successful cleaning of resources even in the case where `exit` or `quit` is called. As always this kind of documentation is a bit hard to find for matlab. I am also curious if the same principles applies for both windows and linux.

In case no cleaning is done here, are there any way to fix it? Like creating the file `finish.m` and letting it contain only a `clear all` call or so?

BR/Patrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `c++`, Matlab has its own garbage collector that takes care of all the "cleaning" stuff for you. So, when you `exit` or `quit` Matlab resources are cleaned for you (!)
If you are using some custom data types or you have data you want to save prior to `exit` you'll need to take care of them by yourself. You can define a custom script containing commands to be executed upon terminating Matlab, see [`finish`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/finish.html) for more details.

Comment: Is there any difference between clicking GUI close button and executing exit (or quit)?? Is finish.m executed by clicking GUI x button?